# TortoiseSVN Hook Scripts No Longer Run

Tags: windows, tortoisesvn

A while a go we set up a post_commit hook script in TortoiseSVN, this is a simple batch file, and this worked fine. We are running Windows 10.

Recently (around the beginning of 2023) this stopped working. TortoiseSVN now reports:

> The hook script returned an error:
> The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

The script executes fine when run manually.

Changing the script to execute to another batch file or a program, results in the same message.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks,
Chris

Edit:

The hook script is client side and is configured as:

> Working Copy Path:
> C:\Temp\Repo

> Command Line To Execute:
> C:\Users\chris\SVNFeeder\testrepo_sync.bat

> Wait for script to finish: True

> Hide the script while running: False

> Always execute the script: True

The batch file contains the following:

```
java -jar  %USERPROFILE%/SVNFeeder/SvnFeeder.jar -c %USERPROFILE%/SVNFeeder/testrepo_configFile
```

The java file updates our Jira server with commit messages.

Changing the command line to execute the java file directly results in the same error, even a simple batch file that only creates a folder doesn't execute.

There is nothing wrong with the batch file or the java file as both execute fine outside of TSVN.

Comment: You need to add details about the hook script and show its code. It’s also unclear if he hook script is configured on the server side or is it a client-side hook script. The error says what it says — some process cannot access some file. Examine the code of your hook script and think what could be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I have just found out that Sophos was blocking the execution of the script.

There was no mention of this in the events page, which didn't help track it down.